# Pandas split column to columns based on comma . but add to existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data unformatted like below in a pandas dataframe. The 3rd row is supposed to be split in 3 columns. But it is added in col1. I have read this data from an excel file.

```
 Col1                                            Col2             Col3
 0.500L PET X12                                  1.0L PET X12
 0.250L RGB X12                                  0.330L RGB X12
 0.330L CAN X24, 0.330L CAN X10, 0.330L CAN X12,
```

What is the best method to get this data formatted as below?

```
 Col1             Col2              Col3
 0.500L PET X12   1.0L PET X12
 0.250L RGB X12   0.330L RGB X12
 0.330L CAN X24   0.330L CAN X10    0.330L CAN X12,
```

Right now `str.split` combined with `fillna` for each col i used. As the dataframe has around 20 columns to combine. I am looking for an alternate method if any.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is add `,` to each column, then join with replace `NaN` and last split with `n=2` for splitting to 3 new columns and last remove possible `,` :

```
df['Col1'] = (df['Col1'].add(', ').fillna('') +
              df['Col2'].add(', ').fillna('') +
              df['Col3'].add(', ').fillna(''))

f = lambda x: x.str.strip(', ')
df[['Col1','Col2','Col3']] = df['Col1'].str.split(', ', n=2, expand=True).apply(f)
    
print (df)
             Col1            Col2            Col3
0  0.500L PET X12    1.0L PET X12                
1  0.250L RGB X12  0.330L RGB X12                
2  0.330L CAN X24  0.330L CAN X10  0.330L CAN X12
```